# QTextEdit change carriage position after setText

Tags: qt, qtextedit

I can't find how to change carriage position on QTextEdit. I add text with setText(or setPlainText) methods, and after this carriage is at the beginning of QTextEdit input field, and I want it to be right after last symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QTextCursor cursor = myQTextEdit.textCursor();
cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
myQTextEdit.setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Or if it won't work, swap lines 2 and 3.